# how to hide style tag from view source like angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-universal

How to hide style tag from view source. 
for example please visit the images have uploaded. this is what i want to achieve.

[style tag in developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY1ba.png)

[no style tag in view source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeF96.png)

After ng-build i am getting all internal style displayed in view source. I want to hide from view Source.

[my project view source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlsfJ.png)

Comment: Is your "style tag in developer tool" from your development environment or from a release build?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer "my project view source" is from production build.

Comment: Do you want this to always happen, or just on SSR rendered builds?

Comment: Just on ssr render if possible. Otherwise always will also work

Comment: It's auto-generated unfortunately. I don't think there's any way to disable it? It's for dynamic theming.

Comment: What's your problem with those styles? The whole point of universal (server side rendering) is to haveing a faster bootstrap.

Comment: Um... Are you using AngularJS Material or Angular Material? You're looking at the wrong documentation site.

Comment: @Edric i am using angular material. By the way i found my answer.  In plateform-server package they have been appending all Style to the view source

Answer (score 1):

In SSR mode, in app.server.module.js, add an `NoRenderServerStylesHost` to override the default ServerStylesHost behavior. for example:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ɵangular_packages_platform_server_platform_server_c as ServerStylesHost } from '@angular/platform-server';

export class NoRenderServerStylesHost extends ServerStylesHost {

    onStylesAdded(additions: Set<string>): void {
        // super.onStylesAdded(additions);
        // additions.forEach((s) => console.log(s));
        // ignore styles added
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // The AppServerModule should import your AppModule followed
        // by the ServerModule from @angular/platform-server.
        AppModule,
        ServerModule,
        ModuleMapLoaderModule,
        ServerTransferStateModule,
    ],
    // Since the bootstrapped component is not inherited from your
    // imported AppModule, it needs to be repeated here.
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [{
        provide: ServerStylesHost,
        useClass: NoRenderServerStylesHost
    }]
})
export class AppServerModule {
}
```

Comment: For Angular 13, ɵangular_packages_platform_server_platform_server_c is removed, So I had to   `import { ɵSharedStylesHost as ServerStylesHost } from '@angular/platform-browser';` , rest everything was same.